# biblatex-dw: display editor string in bibliography, but not in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biblatex-dw

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{Hg\adddot}} ,
    editors = {{Hg\adddot}}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

@book{ebert1989,
    year = {1989},
    title = {Räumt die Steine hinweg: DDR Herbst 1989: geistliche Reden im politischen Aufbruch},
    address = {München},
    publisher = {Claudius},
    isbn = {3532620987},
    editor = {Ebert, Andreas and Haberer, Johanna and Kraft, Friedrich},
    shorttitle = {Steine}
}

    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{ebert1989} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I want the editor string (Hg.) to be displayed in the bibliography, but to disappear in the footnotes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-dw` has an option for that (of course it does).

```
edstringincitations=false,
```

Comment: awesome, +1 for answer and +1 for the greatness of biblatex-dw :)